# Area of a region determined by three functions.

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the area of a region given by $y=\frac{1}{x}$, $y=x^2$, $y=0$ and $x=e$.The intersection points are at $(0, 0)$ and $(0, e)$. So I tried this integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{e}\left(\frac{1}{x}-x^2\right)dx
$$

The result of the integration is:

$$
\ln(x)-\frac{x^3}{3}
$$

And now I try to evaluate from $0$ to $e$:

$$
\left(\ln(e)-\frac{e^3}{3}\right)-\left(\ln(0)-\frac{0^3}{3}\right)
$$

But of course $ln(0)$ is not defined. If I plot it, the region is obviously defined: 
[image]

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula $\frac 1x-x^2$ works if you are trying to find the area between the blue curve  ($y=x^2$) and the green curve ($y=\frac 1x$). However, you are trying to find the curve bound by all four curves, not just those two.

Hence, your desired region is the lower one: above the x-axis, below both the blue and green curves, to the right of the origin and to the left of the orange line. You should split this up into two regions: for $0\le x\le 1$ and $1\le x\le e$. The formula to integrate for the first region is $x^2$ and for the second is $\frac 1x$. The work is simple and you get a simple answer.

You got an unreasonable integral in your efforts because the region, above the blue curve and below the green curve, just to the right of the y-axix, has infinite area.

Comment: Thanks Rory, so if I understood you correctly, what I'm looking for is: 

$$
\int_{0}^{1}{x^2dx}+\int_{1}^{e}{\frac{1}{x}dx}
$$

Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.